# Kotlin: Stop In-Line Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, bluetooth

I have created a few in-line threads and I am now unsure how to stop them. I have one thread to open a bluetooth socket connection, one to close, and one to read the data that uses a custom listview adapter to display the data. I would now like to stop the publishing of the data on the screen via button click. However, I am unsure how to stop these threads. Do I have to move the threads to separate callable classes that inherit from the thread base class?

```
connectButton.setOnClickListener {
            //new thread needed to connect to device and keep rest of app running
            Thread(Runnable {       //connect bluetooth thread
                //cancel discovery in case it was turned on
                btAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()
                try {
                    //connect the socket
                    socket.connect()
                    //run thread on UI to update socket states
                    runOnUiThread(Runnable { conStat(socket) })
                    //new thread needed to read stream and keep rest of app running
                    Thread(Runnable{        //read bluetooth thread
                        //keep reading stream as long as it is open
                        while(true) {
                            readBytes = try {
                                inStream.read(inBuffer)
                            } catch (e: IOException) {
                                Log.d("IN_STREAM: ", "input stream disconnected")
                                break
                            }
                            //return stream information to UI thread as a list view
                            runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                                data.add(inBuffer.copyOf())
                                dataList.adapter = dataListAdapter(this,data)
                                dataList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            })
                        }
                    }).start()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.i("SOCKET: ", "Failed to connect")
                    Log.i("UUID: ", uuid.toString())
                    Log.i("Device: ", pairedDevices.elementAt(position).name)
                    Log.i("Address: ", pairedDevices.elementAt(position).address)
                }
            }).start()
        }

        //cancel button closes the socket connection and returns to main activity
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener {
            //close socket connection
            Thread(Runnable {       //close bluetooth thread
                try {
                    socket.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.i("SOCKET: ", "Could not close socket")
                }
                //return to main activity
                runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                    conStat(socket)
                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                })
            }).start()
        }

        exportButton.setOnClickListener { 
            //how to stop threads?
        }
```

Comment: you might want to keep track of your running threads if you intend to stop them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stopping threads forcefully is just a bad idea, which is why `Thread.stop` is deprecated.
2. So you can use a flag, like

   ```
   val shouldContinue = AtomicBoolean(true)
   ```

   in the data reading thread, replace `while (true)` under "keep reading stream as long as it is open" with `while (shouldContinue.get())`; in the cancel button listener add `shouldContinue.set(false)`.

   Using `var shouldContinue = true` instead of `AtomicBoolean` is likely to work, but not guaranteed to. So it could fail on some devices, but not on yours or in Android emulator, which would be "fun" to debug.
3. It would probably be better to use [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) and [`FutureTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) instead of threads. Or even Kotlin coroutines, but that probably should be left for the future...

Comment: AtomicThankYou!  That did in fact stop the thread.  Async and Future tasks...indeed for the future.  'Till then.  Appreciated

Comment: I added a bit on why `AtomicBoolean`.